# Not getting Device Token in Unity - Push Kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, pushkit

I am facing a problem in Unity for get a device token in push kit.
** I am using Unity 2020.1.8f1 version. Here I have attached the log file which I got from Cloud debugging while testing in P40 Pro.

We look forward to your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have issue with plugin not getting data type notification message, Elvis mine R&D team working on it when they will fixe+F29d this issue we will update you as soon as possible. So we suggest you please work with official Huawei unity plugin its working fine for both data and notification message. Push kit official plugin integration link are given below.

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201367461885740360&fid=0101187876626530001

Thank you.